# VIM: How to avoid substitution within substitution?

Tags: vim, substitution

I created a function to search a custom number of empty lines (with or without spaces) and to replace them with a new (custom) number of empty lines.

```
fun! s:AddRemoveNumbEmptyLines()

if !exists("emptylinesbefore")
  let emptylinesbefore = "How many empty lines do you search? \n (p.e. 2,3  4,  ,3)"
endif  
let b = inputdialog(emptylinesbefore)

if !exists("emptylinesafter")
   let emptylinesafter = "How many empty lines must it be?"
endif  
let c = inputdialog(emptylinesafter)

let m = repeat('\r', c)
exe 's/\(^\s*$\n\)\{'.b.'}/'.m.'/gc'
endfun
```

Let say b = 2,  (2 and more) AND m = 3
If vim finds 4 empty lines it does a substitution to 3 empty lines.
(thats ok).
But when I refuse the substitution request (I use the "c" (confirm) flag) it finds at the same place 3 empty lines and asks again if it has to be replaced with 3 empty lines. When I refuse again, it finds at the same place, 2 empty lines and asks again if I want to do a substitution.

How can I avoid these multiple substitution requests (at the same place)?
Hope I made myself clear :)

Comment: Maybe use `%s` instead of `s`? And normally it should work (it will not recurse in an infinite loop).

Comment: @Benoit, yes I checked it also with %s and "'<,'>".   It does a subsitution request within another substitution when I don't accept the substitution request (replace with \r\r\r - (y/n/a/q...etc)).

Comment: resolved it! I just had to check for a non space \S in the line before and the line after. My new exe = 's/^.*\S\+.*\n\zs\\(^\s*$\n\\)\{'.b.'}\ze\s*\S\+/'.m.'/gc

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer and accept it so that people (and machines) will know that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved it! I just had to check for a non space \S in the line before and the line after.

```
My new exe = 's/^.*\S\+.*\n\zs\(^\s*$\n\)\{'.b.'}\ze\s*\S\+/'.m.'/gc
```